# Reference request : table of quantum Clebsch-Gordan coefficient

Tags: reference-request, qa.quantum-algebra, quantum-groups

From a quick Google search, one can find a table of the first Clebsch-Gordan coefficient. For example [this table](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Table_of_Clebsch%E2%80%93Gordan_coefficients). Those are used to pass between the tensor product bases and the bases as sum of irreducible of the tensor product of two irreducibles representations of $U(\frak{sl_2})$.

I was wondering if there is such a table somewhere for the quantum Clebsch-Gordan coefficient, that is those occuring when you replace $U(\frak{sl_2})$ with $U_q(\frak{sl_2})$.

Answer (score 5):

For rank-two quantum groups the Clebsch-Gordan coefficients are tabulated in [arXiv:1004.5456](https://arxiv.org/abs/1004.5456) by Ardonne and Slingerland. This also includes mathematica notebooks to perform these and similar calculations.

More tables are in [Hegde & Ramadevi.](http://reports.ias.ac.in/report/20372/quantum-clebsch-gordan-coefficients-and-conformal-field-theory)